# DENSE-RANK usage for below query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The below is the source table:

```
Order_Id  ====  Job_No  ====  Address  ====   Delivery_Month 
==============================================================
  06543         77771         Newyork         January               
  06543         66662         North NY        February              
  06543         11113         Cupertino       March                 
  06545         22225         Johanseburg     September
  06545         88889         Kingsmead       July
  06540         77773         Sydney          April
  06540         22228         Melbourne       November
  06876         11112         Kandy           August
```

I want the query for the above table with following clauses:

1] Sort By Order_ID

```
Order_Id  ====  Job_No  ====  Address  ====   Delivery_Month ==== Rank
========================================================================
  06540         77773         Sydney          April                1
  06540         22228         Melbourne       November             1
  06543         77771         Newyork         January              2
  06543         66662         North NY        February             2
  06543         11113         Cupertino       March                2
  06545         22225         Johanseburg     September            3
  06545         88889         Kingsmead       July                 3    
  06876         11112         Kandy           August               4
```

This is working for me with ranking on order_id(same order id should have same rank)

2] Sort by Job should give below output (with rank based on same order_id)

```
Order_Id  ====  Job_No  ====  Address  ====   Delivery_Month ==== Rank
========================================================================
  06876         11112         Kandy           August               1
  06543         11113         Cupertino       March                2
  06545         22225         Johanseburg     September            3
  06540         22228         Melbourne       November             4
  06543         66662         North NY        February             2
  06543         77771         Newyork         January              2
  06540         77773         Sydney          April                4
  06545         88889         Kingsmead       July                 3
```

Comment: Is this possible for  clause no 2]

Comment: Yes it is possible! apply rank on order_id and put job_no in order by clause.

Answer (score 3):

The values in the `select` clause should not bother you. They are independent to the `order by` clause:

```
select order_id, job_no, address, delivery_month,
   dense_rank() over (order by order_id) as rank
from table
order by job_no;
```